# Does anyone know of a voicechanger that i can use with skype?

Tags: pulseaudio, skype, microphone, voip

Does anyone know of a live voice changer that I can connect to Skype so that I can have some fun with my friends?

Comment: Close-voters: Skype is commonly used on Ubuntu, and a lot of software that works with Skype is Windows-only. I don't see any reason this would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Clownfish for Skype](http://clownfish-translator.com/linux.html). I don't know exactly how good it is, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Currently clownfish doesn't have a voicechanger in the linux version. But the translation functionality and the art messages should be enough for now :) thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I am using Voice Changer Software Diamond, available at audio4fun.com
I am using Windows and that is a good voice changer with many effects and presets. They also have an add-on store to download more presets. (I went and download some scary voices there).

Comment: You can improve your answer by including a real link (not just the website name) and some instructions for installation.